# check FormGroup if any control value changed or not? Is there any property? In Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 15 editable items in FormGroup which are textbox and Select(dropdown). I just want to know if user edited(means changed value) any items. Is there any direct property or something so that I can check if any item value has been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myForm: FormGroup;
message: string;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    email: ''
  });

  this.onChanges();
}
```

Notice how we call an onChanges method in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook after having initialized our form. Here’s the content of our onChanges method:

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.message =
    `Hello ${val.name}`;
  });
}
```

You can also listen for changes on specific form controls instead of the whole form group:

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.message = `My name is ${val}.`;
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this Code
`formGroupEdited:boolean=false;
checkIfFormGroupEdited() {
    this.assetDetailForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.formGroupEdited = true;
      console.log(this.formGroupEdited, "formEdited");
    });
  }`

Why it is giving me true at the load time?

Comment: @VishalMittal one solution is to check if changed value is same as default value  formGroupEdited will be false.

Comment: Call to the "checkIfFormGroupEdited()" function AFTER you create this.formGroupEdited. (Put fromGroupEdited=false inside the function too)

Comment: There is also the statusChanges event, which emits an event when validation status of the form changes. That means if a user edited the form an event will be emit.